# Make a property required based on another property of a generic interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an interface for a react component. There are a bunch of properties there, but I want one property to affect the others.
So, what I have is:

```
export interface IMyAwesomeComponentProps<T = {}> {
    className: string
    defaultPath?: ISomeOtherInterface<T>

    // more properties...
    // ...and finally

    isDraggable?: boolean
    onDrag?: () => {}
}
```

This thing is implemented like so:

```
export class MyAwesomeComponent<T> extends React.Component<IMyAwesomeComponentProps<T>> {
   //...
}
```

So, what I what to do is when I pass the "isDraggable" as "true", I want the "onDrag" to be **required**.

To resolve this, I first excluded "onDrag" function from the interface and made a new type. Then I made a utility type which basically says "if that "isDraggable" thing is true, then return the interface combined with "TDraggableProps" otherwise just give me the interface back".
Overall it looks like this:

```
type TDraggableProps = {  
  onDrag: () => void
  // maybe some more props  
}

type Test<I extends ITreeProps> = I['isDraggable'] extends true ? I & TDraggableProps : I

export class MyAwesomeComponent<T> extends React.Component<Test<IMyAwesomeComponentProps<T>>>
```

Aaaand, this kinda works except it's not. And I have no idea what to do with that generic that comes into the interface.

Comment: If isDraggable is false, do you want onDrag to be optional or not be in there at all? What if isDraggable is not provided?

Comment: Generally speaking you're looking for something along the lines of `{ isDraggable: true, onDrag: DragFunction } | { isDraggable: false }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)

```
type Props = {
  isDraggable: true;
  onDrag: () => void;
} | {
  isDraggable: false;
}

const Component = (props: Props) => {}

Component({ isDraggable: false }); // Ok
Component({ isDraggable: true }); // Error onDrag is missing
Component({ isDraggable: true, onDrag: () => {} }); // Ok
```

If you need to add some common props you can either make the types as interface and extend some base interface, or just extract them to a separate type and join to your props

```
type Props = {
  isDraggable: true;
  onDrag: () => void;
} | {
  isDraggable: false;
}

type StaticProps = {
  className: string;
}

const Component = (props: Props & StaticProps) => {}

Component({ isDraggable: false, className: "123" });
Component({ isDraggable: true, className: "123" }); // Error onDrag is missing
Component({ isDraggable: true, onDrag: () => {}, className: "123" }); // Ok
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change your interface IMyAwesomeComponentProps signature by creating a IDraggable interface and include it in your IMyAwesomeComponentProps. Of course assuming here that having the situation where `isDraggable = false` and the `onDrag is defined` is useless...

Something like this :

```
    interface ITest<T = {}> {
    a: string;
    b: IInner<T>;
    isDraggable?: IIsDragble;
}

interface IIsDragble {
    onDrag: () => void;
}

const a: ITest = {
    a: "dsd",
    b: {
        valInner: "ssdds",
    },
};

const b: ITest = {
    a: "dsd",
    b: {
        valInner: "ssdds",
    },
    isDraggable: {
        onDrag: () => true,
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make the Props a type then move all interface for all the common properties and for different properties, I think this approach looks clean and readable:

```
interface Common {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;
}

interface RequiredB {
  a: true;
  b: () => {}
}

interface OptionalB {
  a: false;
  b?: () => {}
}

type Props = Common & (RequiredB | OptionalB);

const obj: Props = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3,
  //a: false, // b is not required now
  //a: true, // b is required now
}
```